# Rewrite /?rest_route=/ link to /wp-json/ without changing default permalink structure in apache

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules, rest-api, apache

How to rewrite url of wordpress rest api from `http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/` to `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/` without changing (default) permalink structure? Need this for apache (htaccess).

In nginx it would be like this:

`location ~ ^/wp-json/ {
    rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by this lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-json/(.*) /?rest_route=/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Strictly speaking, this rewrites from `/wp-json/wp/v2/` to `/?test_route=/wp/v2/`, which is what you require (and what the Nginx directives do), but this is the opposite of what you described in your question.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you solve this? I have written your code, but it always redirects to the xampp dashboard instead of wp-json/wp/v2

Comment: Is there alternative to editing the .htaccess file, In my circumstance I am hitting endpoints on a wordpress plugin and can't rely on my users being able to edit a .htacces file